# ERROR: Insufficient space in file

Tags: join, sas, left-join, space, proc-sql

I am trying to create a hybrid table, combining some fields from two massive data sets. I'm running this in SAS EG 7.2.

I initially tried joining the two tables, but I got the following message:

```
    ERROR: Insufficient space in file JVTEST.GT_IFRS_JOIN1_MAY.DATA.
    ERROR: File JVTEST.GT_IFRS_JOIN1_MAY.DATA is damaged. I/O processing did not complete.
```

The join I am doing contains fewer columns than both of the tables seen individually. I am getting the same error when I execute the program.

In the code, I am first joining table (a) to a table containing Keys (b) for both tables.

Table

The code looks like this:

```
 Proc SQL; 
 Create Table GT_IFRS_Join1_May as 
 Select 
 a.DataDate,
 a.Company,
 a.ContractID,
 a.ProductGrouping,
 a.LocalProductGrouping,
 a.OriginalMaturityDt,
 a.CurrentMaturityDt,
 a.OpeningDt,
 a.LocalPurpose,
 a.SecuritizationFlg,
 a.SourceSystem,
 a.refinanced_flag,
 a.ManagementStatus,
 a.LocalManagementStatus,
 a.AmountGranted,
 a.CurrentLimit,
 a.ProductCode,
 a.SpecificLocalProvision,
 a.default_flag,
 a.onBal_neg,
 a.onBal_no_neg,
 a.offBal_neg,
 a.offBal_no_neg,
 a.Portfolio,
 a.LoanTerm,
 a.CurrentLoanTerm,
 a.MonthonDefault,
 a.AssetClass,
 a.GuaranteeValue,
 a.CurrentGuaranteeValue,
 a.RemainingLoan,
 a.dtv,
 a.u_dtv,
 a.ltv,
 a.u_ltv,
 a.percentageUsed,
 a.SME_Factor_corp,
 a.K1,
 a.K2,
 a.DQ_K1_GROUP,
 a.DQ_K2_GROUP,
 a.DQ_K1,
 a.DQ_K2,
 a.EAD,
 a.EAD_mora,
 a.EAD_total,
 a.DQ_PD,
 a.DQ_PD_GROUP,
 a.ProductGrouper,
 a.LGD_TEMP,
 a.riesgoAgregadoTitular,
 a.EL, 
 b.contractID,
 b.SourceKey as ContractWR
 From jvtest.contractmapping as a
 left Join GT.great_table_loc_2018_5_npl as b
 on a.contractid = b.contractid;
 quit; 

 Proc SQL;
 Create table jvtest.GT_IFRS_JOIN1_MAY as 
 Select a.*,
 b.Itaca_portfolio,
 b.Finrep_Sector,
 b.RiskBucket,
 b.Status,
 b.Onbalance_Nok,
 b.Offbalance_Nok,
 b.EAD_Nok,
 b.Stage,
 b.P2_Prov_Nok
 From work.GT_IFRS_JOIN1_May as a
 Left join jvtest._09_forfinance as b
 on a.ContractWR = b.contractID; 
 Quit;
```

Do you have any ideas on why this is happening? As mentioned, the new hybrid table is in theory a lot smaller than any of the two tables seen individually. Additionally, do you know how to circumvent the error?

Thanks!

Comment: What does your SQL look like?

Comment: Do any notes in your log say something about a cartesian product that cannot be optimized? How much space do you have available on your computer?

Comment: The only code I have is typed up above, not sure I understand what you mean when you say my SQL? Could you please ellaborate? :)

Comment: Stu, No notes about Cartesian products, the disk space is virtually endless. The Two files individually are 4.4gb and 4.6gb respectively

Comment: Sounds like you are doing a many-to-many join. How many observations per value of `a.ContractWR`? per value of `b.contractID`?

Comment: Hi Tom, yes you are right; there is a 1-n relationship (ContractID 1 - ContractWR n). 'n' varies!

Comment: What are the row counts of the tables? What are row counts of the join (without creating the table) `select count(*) from A left join B on A.key1=B.key2`.  What are the `Proc CONTENTS` of the tables ? What is the work case 1-n ? 1-1000 ?  Can you show the 1-n key freq distribution of B ? `select groupN, count(*) as Freq from (select key, count(*) as groupN from B group by key) group by groupN` ?

Comment: Maybe your SAS isn't configured the way it is supposed to be. Or, it can be an I/O lag issue on the server side (I assumed, 'cause SAS EG). Could you try to create the table in workspace with other name? And, then everything on disk (with valid librefs)?

Comment: How long does the query run to fill up the "virtually endless" disk? (If not too long, the assumption may be wrong.) Does this run on a remote server? What are the libname assignments (`libname _all_ list;`) for `work` and `jvtest`? what exactly is the free space on the corresponding drives/mount points during the execution of the second query? Does the server has any quotas configured? Do you have char columns with large length w/o `compress=yes`?

Comment: post the whole log!

Comment: SAMKART, you were right, the issue is now resolved. I tired workspace and new name, it ran smoothly. Then Data Set to store in correct lib. Thanks!